# Paging doesn't work in the Joomla Article Manager in the admin section

Tags: session, joomla, paging, joomla1.5

I inherited a Joomla site that is having a problem with the article manager in the admin section. The pagination doesn't work! If I click the page number, forward, back, or page size, nothing happens! So I found out that someone had previously installed the iJoomla SEO plugin, but it never worked so they removed it. I think it is incompatible with the version I have.

I setup a local environment with almost the same setup (I have 5.2.11 vs the servers 5.2.13) with Wamp Server, and I found that some of the session variables are missing! When dumped via print_r(), the $_SESSION variable is missing the "com_content", "global", and "com_plugins" arrays! So I guess that is the reason that paging doesn't work, because the "com_content" array looks like it has paging info in it. (maybe I'm wrong)

So I'm running Version 1.5.13
on PHP Version 5.2.13

Anyone know why this would happen? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One suggestion I have which might fix a broken install of Joomla would be to upgrade to the latest version. This is good practice anyway and might help. The latest version of Joomla is 1.5.15.

Comment: I don't really consider an upgrade a solution to a problem like this, but I did do an upgrade and it worked!  I didn't expect the upgrade to be as easy as it was, but I'm still scared that I couldn't find the root cause!?

Comment: Agreed. Not an answer as to why you were having the problem, just a possible way of fixing it. Glad the upgrade seems to have helped.